# How to write such regexp

Tags: regex, pseudocode

Need regexp for following data:

```
#file "scripts\generate.c";;
void Generate()

adsasd
asdasdas
asdasd
#file "a.c";;
void asdad()
asdasd
asdasd
```

which will return file and code like so:

```
Array(
    [0] => scripts\generate.c
    [1] => 
            void Generate()
               
            adsasd
            asdasdas
            asdasd
)
```

... and same for `#file "a.c";;`

Comment: 1. /#file "(.*)";;((?!#file .*).)*/ims

2. /#file "?(.*)";;
(.*)/ims - seems to work, but only if is endline character before #file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try was nearby correct. Just change `((?!#file .*).)*` to `((?:(?!#file).)*)` and also add the modifier `g` to get all occurrences.

It should look than like this: `/#file "([^"]*)";;((?:(?!#file).)*)/gims`

Test it here: http://www.regex101.com/r/cC5tK5

Comment: Great! Thanks)
p.s. Beer and regex's aren't compatible :)

Comment: depends on the order of them ;-)